# rails rspec controller test ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: testing, rspec, controller, nested-routes

My routes looks like this

```
  resources :stores, :except => [:destroy] do
    resources :toys, :member => {:destroy => :delete}
  end
```

my objects controller spec look like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ToysController do

    describe "GET index" do
        it "assigns all toys as @toys" do
          toy11 = Factory(:toy, :is_shiny => true)
          toy12 = Factory(:toy,:is_shiny => false)
          get :index
          assigns(:toys).should eq([toy12,toy11 ])
        end
      end
    end
end
```

I got the following error

```
 Failure/Error: get :index
 ActionController::RoutingError:
 No route matches {:controller=>"toys"}
```

Since the toys resource is nested under stores resources its not able to get toys_path route so i think so the spec is failing.

How do i pass the spec?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to not sending store_id to tyos index.
Had i sent

```
:store_id => @store.id in get :index
```

it would have passed.